# How to remove product base from WooCommerce product permalinks

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, permalinks

I read here some information of the issue but didn't find any solution. Is it possible to remove product base using some lines of code for example a filter in `functions.php` of my theme or plugin? So that the permalinks will be like `domain.com/some-product` instead of `domain.com/product-base/some-product`

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use **free** [Premmerce WooCommerce Permalink Manager Pro](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-permalink-manager/) plugin that allow you to change the product permalinks like you are expecting. See this screenshot of the allowed settings with this plugin:

[image]

Comment: @stckvrw Nobody is going to hack this plugin for you… I use it just as it is. You can inspect the plugin source code and pick the necessary code to make it yours if you like…